# How to use multiple ternary operator with Vue js in a template?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex, conditional-operator

I'm expecting to return three, more than two different values depending on data in a template. I know how to use it if two conditions, but is there a way to use more than two conditions ? Gives me a syntaxes error.

```js
<option 
  {{ change === 1 ? 'One change' : change === 2 ? 'Two changes' : change === 3 ? 'Three changes'}}</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood You correctly, please take a look at following snippet: (You can map types of change and return them with computed property )

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      changes: [1,2,3],
      changeTypes: new Map([
        [1, 'One change'],
        [2, 'Two changes'],
        [3, 'Three changes']
      ])
    };
  },
  computed: {
    getChanges() {
      return this.changes.map(c => {
        return this.changeTypes.get(c)
      })
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <select>
  <option v-for="change in getChanges">
    {{ change }}
  </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really, I'm doing a mapping already so the best approach would be to write this logic in one line, simply using ternary operator

Comment: @bob hey mate, You should avoid putting logic in template, create computed property or method instead :)

Comment: btw, Your conditions with ternary just need last case: `change === 1 ? 'One change' : change === 2 ? 'Two changes' : change === 3 ? 'Three changes' : ''`

Comment: @bob The best approach is to move this logic to a computed in order to not evaluate it on each render. And the best way to write it in a computed is to not use nested ternaries because they are unreadable.